# MySQL dot-traversal... possible?

Tags: sql, mysql, orm

So I'm working on a CMS that will allow users to "traverse" through database tables. I'm having some trouble implementing it though, and am wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

```
Table: house
name (varchar), town (relationship, using the rel table)

Table: town
name(varchar), state (relationship, using the rel table)

Table: state
name(varchar)

Table: rel
id1, id2, rel_type
```

The following example shows its intended usage. It reads, "Find 10 houses within the state of Alaska, ordered by name".

```
<?php
$Record = new Pod('house');
$Record->findRecords('name ASC', 10, "town.state.name = 'Alaska'");
?>
```

As a side note, I can easily find houses within a town name, since MySQL supports [table][dot][column_name]:

```
<?php
$Record = new Pod('house');
$Record->findRecords('name ASC', 10, "town.name = 'Great Falls'");
?>
```

I could always put a "state" field into the "house" table directly, but users need the ability to reference columns from other columns. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), for example:

```
SELECT
   house.*
FROM
   house
   JOIN town ON town.id = house.town
   JOIN state ON state.id = town.state
WHERE state.name = 'Alaska'
```

The query would work with 1:N relationships, but since you are using M:N relationships (implemented in a weird way), you will need to join a few more tables.

This makes the object model a little more complex, you will have to think about a new API for these kind of queries. Or use (see how it's done in) an existing ORM system.

To explain the 1:N vs M:N issue - it's not very common to have IDs pointing to other tables without foreign key constraints in well-designed databases. The usual way to model M:N relationships would be:

- house: id int (PK), name varchar
- house_town: house int (PK, FK references house.id), town int (PK, FK references town.id)
- town: id int (PK), name varchar

And for 1:N relationships:

- house: id int (PK), name varchar, town int (FK references town.id)
- town: id int (PK), name varchar